# Who influenced anabaptist teachings the most and where did anabaptist teachings come from?

Tags: reformation, germany, anabaptism, zwingli

I know that Switzerland and southern Germany was the birthplace of anabaptism, did it come from Ulrich Zwingli? Or was there another more influential person out of the reformation that encouraged anabaptism?

Modern anabaptist churches (to my knowledge) are all descendents of German Brethren churches. Where would that put Switzerland?

Comment: The Wikipedia article about Anabaptism is pretty good: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anabaptism.  Also, the article about the Swiss Brethren details that branch: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_Brethren.